# is there any contractable space with three points?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

i'm looking for a three point contractible topological space, is this example true?
T={{(0,1]},{(1,2]},{(0,2]},{(0,3]},empty set}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your $T$ mentions (at least) four points and doesn't define a topology.

Here's a hint. Every indiscrete space is contractible; indeed, if $X$ is indiscrete, then any function $H : X \times [0,1] \to X$ is a homotopy since every function whose codomain is indiscrete is continuous.

Comment: i tried to define a topology on three points a=(0,1] , b=(1,2] , c=(2,3] ....https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_topological_space

Comment: @user297564: Why did you give your points such weird names? Why not just $a,b,c$, or even $1,2,3$? Also, you have that $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ are open, but $\{a\}\cup\{b\}=\{a,b\}$ is not.

Comment: @user297564: I think you made matters more confusing for yourself than you needed to by taking the *points* of your space to be *subsets* of $\mathbb{R}$. You have included (the singletons of) $(0,1]$, $(1,2]$, $(0,2]$ and $(0,3]$ in your definition of $T$, meaning your space must have at least four points. If you meant that $(0,1]$, $(1,2]$, $(0,2]$ and $(0,3]$ are the *open sets* of your space, then your space has infinitely many points. In any case, the topology you define is not a topology of a finite space.

Comment: ow! thanks! i got it